# suggestion for end of integer array marker

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, int

I've an array of fixed size in `C`. There I might have any number (less than the array size) of useful element. Now I need only my useful element. So I'm thinking of using an `end of array` marker for integer array. First of all

---

a) Is this possible?

b) If possible, How?

Comment: Impossible. Imagine what happens when all of the array has useful elements ... there is no space for the marker. Use a helper variable with how many elements are useful.

Comment: @pmg Well, if you think of strings they're arrays and they do have an end of string marker (null `\0`). All you need to do is creating an array whose size is one slot larger than the needed elements.

Comment: @nadirs: you're right. If the OP can use a specific value for the marker (eg: `0`, `42`, `-8888`, `INT_MAX`, `INT_MIN`) it is possible.

Comment: @pmg In fact it would help if the OP could specify the possible values (or ranges) of integers in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a slightly different approach

```
struct IntArray
{
  int data[N];
  int size; // <-- use this to keep track of the size.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Logically it is possible if you can find unique integer number that can act as END_OF_ARRAY , and will not be there in your set of useful number ...

you just need to to add it explicitly at end ... and check for number later that will indicate end

Answer (score 2):

It depends what it is an array of and what values are valid.

You say you have an array of int, use any value that is not valid for the list.  If all entries are positive, use a negative number for the end.  If the values are all under INT_MAX, use that as the end marker.

Answer (score 1):

You can always treat your array as an buffer and keep track of current number of useful elements.

```
struct buffer 
{ 
     int* array;
     size_t size;
}
```

Comment: That's the approach I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create an integer variable called `end_of_array_marker`.

Does it need to be more complicated than this ?

Comment: I often don't understand questions here on SO.  I plough on regardless.

Answer (score 0):

There are a two ways to do that (if the int value could have any possible value for int).

---

First option: **Storing the count of elements in your array,** and increase the value if you add/remove items.

```
int count;
int *array;
```

---

Second option: **Making a structure with the pointer to the next variable in the array.** If its `NULL` you have reached the end of your list.

```
struct Item {
    int i;
    struct Item *next;
}
// pointing at the start adress:
struct Item *start = NULL;
// adding first item:
start = malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
start->i = 123;
start->next = NULL // mark the current end of list (not needed if you add a value right after the first)
// adding second item:
start->next = malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
start->next->i = 456;
start->next->next = NULL
// etc
```